# how to bind hidden field value to gridview template field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am storing a value in hidden field and these value I want to bind to grid view in template field please help me guys

```
private void BindGridTL()
{
    clsTeamLeadDashboard clsTeamLead = new clsTeamLeadDashboard();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    clsTeamLead.Month = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
    clsTeamLead.Year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
    ds = clsTeamLead.BindTLDashBoardDatewise();
    Label lblName = (Label)GridView1.FindControl("lblName");
    lblName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
    hdName.Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNameh" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="hdName.value"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>

Comment: above code is for grid view